# Gaining more flags

Tags: discussion

I have started utilising the flag system more often as of late and I have noticed that I have accumulated flags.

What I mean is I originally had the ability to flag ten posts, before I "ran out of flags to use". Currently I have the ability to flag 21 posts should I so desire.

My question is by what system have I gained flags?

Comment: Might I suggest you read the Help portion of the website (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) before posting questions like this - it is unlikely you are the first person to have this question. If you type flags into the search box on the help page the first result would have answered your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [explained by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890),

> You start with 10 flags per day.
>
> Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as many as 100 per day.
>
> Currently, that means you get an extra flag per day for every 2000 reputation points or 10 *net* helpful flags (helpful-declined).